# How do I push a int variable from my code, into a text file as binary?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to push one integer variable, pushups, and save it into a binary file.
This is the way that I am attempting to do so.

```
void binaryWorkout(Workout routine, int i)
{

    
    ofstream file("binaryFile.txt");

    file.open("binaryFile.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
    int pushups;

    if (i == 1)
    {
        pushups = routine.getPushups();

        file << pushups;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "No data entered";
    }

    file.close();
}
```

I thought this was the proper method, but each time I open the binaryFile.txt there is nothing saved into it.

Is this the proper method to do so and the problem is where I have the file saved?
Or am I doing this incorrectly?
Thanks

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: The constructor for `ofstream` already opens the file for you. You should remove this constructor call. Otherwise, code looks alright. Check if the `i == 1` branch is executed by putting a print statement inside of it. Also you probably don't want to use the "txt" extension if you are storing data in binary format.

Comment: 1) When you specify a filename in the constructor, the file gets opened automatically, thus no need to open it explicitly. Try `std::ofstream file("binaryFile.txt", std::ios::binary);`. 2) The `operator <<` performs so-called _formatted_ output, i.e., textual, not binary. For binary output, i.e., for writing raw bytes representation of `int`, you need _unformatted_ output, by using the [`write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) method. 3) No need to call `close()` explicitly, the file will be automatically closed by destructor of `std::ofstream`.